# Error al suavizar series de tiempo con savgol_filter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, scipy

Intento suavizar la siguiente serie de tiempo

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

symbol = 'BTC-USD'
#df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', '2019-01-01', '2019-04-01')
bitcoin = yf.download("^IBEX", start="2019-07-19", end = "2019-08-17")
```

Para ello utilizo el método  **savgol_filter**

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

smoothed_2dg = savgol_filter(bitcoin, window_length = 5, polyorder = 2)
smoothed_2dg

smoothed_1dg = savgol_filter(bitcoin, window_length = 5, polyorder = 1)
smoothed_1dg

bitcoin['smoothed_2dg'] = smoothed_2dg
bitcoin['smoothed_1dg'] = smoothed_1dg
```

Me devuelve el error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'smoothed_2dg'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3573         try:
-> 3574             loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
   3575         except KeyError:

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 

KeyError: 'smoothed_2dg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-946476b3b09b> in <module>
      7 smoothed_1dg
      8 
----> 9 bitcoin['smoothed_2dg'] = smoothed_2dg
     10 bitcoin['smoothed_1dg'] = smoothed_1dg

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3038         else:
   3039             # set column
-> 3040             self._set_item(key, value)
   3041 
   3042     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3115         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3116         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 3117         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3118 
   3119         # check if we are modifying a copy

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3575         except KeyError:
   3576             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 3577             self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
   3578             return
   3579 

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1187             value = _safe_reshape(value, (1,) + value.shape)
   1188 
-> 1189         block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim, placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
   1190 
   1191         for blkno, count in _fast_count_smallints(self.blknos[loc:]):

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   2720         values = DatetimeArray._simple_new(values, dtype=dtype)
   2721 
-> 2722     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2723 
   2724 

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    129         if self._validate_ndim and self.ndim and len(self.mgr_locs) != len(self.values):
    130             raise ValueError(
--> 131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    132                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"
    133             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El error radicā en que el primer parámetro que hay que dar al método savgol_filter, **NO** es un DataFrame, si no una serie. En este caso tenemos que darle bitcoin["Close"]